# How to load PHP file into DIV by jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a website and I have this on the side menu :

`<a href="#" class="leftMenu" id="contact">Contact Us</a>`

then I have this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#contact").click(function(){
    $("#contents").load('home.php');
  });
});
```

and I have this DIV inside my page :

`<div class="contentWrapper" id="contents"></div>`

Obviously, what I am trying to do is to load home.php when I click on the Contact Us hyperlink, which doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you show us where you have set this up?

Comment: Do you get any errors? This code should work.

Comment: Your error is probably in home.php. Try using firebug (or Developer console) to watch the request and response.

Comment: Does home.php really exist where specified?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot show where this is set up due to customer request. However, I am very sure that my jQuery is working as the toggling of link display works. However, when I click on the Contact Us link, it doesn't load up the contents inside the div as it should.

Comment: I've been testing this all morning, and can't get $.load('file.html') NOT to work. It seems to get it always. Can you tell about your folder structure, do you include files from subfolders and such.

Comment: Is the `<script></script>` closure inside `#contents`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

add `home.php` page url instead of file name.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#contact").click(function(){
    $("#contents").load('url to home.php');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for some weird reasons, it worked! But I am wondering why it doesn't work without the URL. It should be the same, right?

Comment: Yes, relative URL's should work.  Try appending using `/home.php`?

Comment: how can you load two different pages in two different div in one click of a button?

Comment: after loading dose it takes the CSS style from the destination page?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `$.load()` like this, to get more data of whats happening. When you see the error message, you probably can solve it yourself ^^

```
$("#contents").load("home.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
      // alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      console.log(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

@user2805663 I know this post is pretty old but though let me post the solution it might help someone else, as it helped me.

Thanks to @Mangala Edirisinghe

by following method you can load two separate files in two different DIVs with single click(Link).

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#clickableLink").click(function(){ 
  $("#contents").load('url/file1.php');
  $("#contents2").load('url/file2.php'); 
 }); 
});
```

Comment: dose it maintain the css style too?

Comment: @KamelLabiad Yes it does maintain because normally you load your CSS in the HEAD section so it's available in DOM already.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the path of "**home.php**" from index **dir** and not from script dir.

If you site is :

```
/
  index.php  
  scripts
     /script.js 
     /home.php
```

You have to modify your parameter passing "**scripts/home.php**"