# Loading php content in div only

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I have gone through this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524228/how-to-load-php-file-into-div-by-jquery) here at stackoverflow, but I cant seem to get the div loaded here is my code

```
<div id="leftmenu" style="font-size:20px;position:absolute;top:12%;bottom:0;right:0;left:2%;">
                <a href="#" id="details"> Form </a>
</div>

<div id="content" style="font-size:20px;position:absolute;top:12%;bottom:0;right:10%;left:12%;">
</div>

<script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#details").click(function(){
                $("#content").load('student_details.php');
            });
          });
</script>
```

Edit: Made change to Load part but still does not work for me

Edit 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title> test </title> 
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="leftmenu" style="font-size:20px;position:absolute;top:12%;bottom:0;right:0;left:2%;width:100px;height:100px;">
                <a href="#" id="details"> Form </a>
        </div>

        <div id="content" style="font-size:20px;position:absolute;top:12%;bottom:0;right:10%;left:12%;">
        </div>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#details").click(function(){
                $("#content").load('load.html');
            });
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The following code also fails to work the load.html file is present in D: drive have I done something wrong in div? or maybe the script tag?

the content of load.html is " this works "

Comment: `$("#content").load('student_details.php');`

Comment: check if given url is valid!

Comment: Hi,i have tried that no luck

Comment: try using full url instead. $("#content").load('site.com/something/student_details.php');

Comment: Does your `<div>` have any size on screen that gives it the ability to be clicked??  If the div's width/height are `0px` it will be kind of hard to click on it.  Use your browsers developer tools to verify this.

Comment: Hi, "./student_details.php"  and localhost/Practice/student_details.php both not working

Comment: @ Crackertastic 42px x 22px

Comment: @Crackertastic the .php page has only <?php echo "Name : abcd" ?>

Comment: Does executing `student_details.php` by itself produce an error?  Also, if an error is occurring and errors are being suppressed, that may be part of your problem.  One thing that I could point out is the lack of a semicolon in your `echo` statement, per your comment above.    `<?php echo "Name : abcd" ?>` should be `<?php echo "Name : abcd"; ?>`

Comment: Hi, Errors are not suppressed. I forgot type the semicolon in above comment.I will first try loading the above for a simple html page.Let me see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

The url has to be passed as an string literal enclosed within `''` or `""`

```
$("#content").load('student_details.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

The file path has to be a string. So instead of:

```
$("#content").load(student_details.php);
```

You would put:

```
$("#content").load("student_details.php");
```