# Page Not Recognising Script or Location of Load File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page that is not recognising this script:

```
<div id='userInfo'></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = $("#dropdown").find(":selected").val();
    //alert('Select:'); 
    // load it in the userInfo div above
    $('#userInfo').load('data.php?id=' + id);
    $("#dropdown").change(function(){

    // get the selected user's id
    var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    //alert('Select:'); 
    // load it in the userInfo div above
    $('#userInfo').load('data.php?id=' + id);

    });
});
</script>
```

It might recognise the script but the data.php its looking for is not being picked up even though it is in the same directory.  The select statement is working fine.  I have tried this on two separate servers, it works on one and not on the other.  I need it to work on the one its not working on of course.

The one its working on the form is a directory called /form and this one is in a directory called /letters on a subdomain.  How do I get it to recognise the where data.php is?

Comment: This answer might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524228/how-to-load-php-file-into-div-by-jquery

Comment: I've tried that and its not working :-( I did http://mywebsite.co.uk/bro/letters/data.php  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out for some time.  Try using relative url, like `/data.php`.  If that doesn't work, there could be an issue with the browser you're working with.  Local files do not load through Ajax on the browser for security reasons.

I suggest doing a simple jquery AJAX call with `$.ajax()`.  Send the id as a GET parameter, dynamically generate what you need via JSON, and on `success` function, fill in your `div` with what you generated and sent to the client file from your PHP backend.  Good luck!