# How to load js inside every div separately?

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to load JS for each div. Now it only loads for the first div.

There are multiple posts in same page.
I need to load the post.php  inside  every #box div.

Is it possible in this way or is there some better way to do this ?

```
<h2>title: <?php echo $post_title ?></h2>
<div id="box" >
  <script type="text/javascript" >
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#box').load('post.php?id=<?=$post_id?>')
   });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique. Try using `class="box"` instead.

Comment: *"inside every #box div."* - The concept of doing *anything* with "every #box div" is problematic given that element IDs are supposed to be unique. Is your PHP `$post_id` supposed to be unique per div (perhaps in a PHP loop), or...?

Comment: yes  $post_id is unique for each post

Comment: [works well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12524381/6521116)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load PHP file into DIV by jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524228/how-to-load-php-file-into-div-by-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Id's` are supposed to be unique, so use `class` instead like:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
...

$('.box').load('post.php?id=<?=$post_id?>');
```

The above statement will load the content in every `div` having class `box`

Comment: This is definitely the right approach, however since the post ID is going to be different on every div, this would need to be a little more complex - for example, writing the post ID as an HTML attribute on the DIV and using that in the load() call.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, you have use `<div id="box">`, merge this div with your id like this `<div id="box <?php echo $post_id;?>">` so each time it will genrate unique div and it will be easy solution for you to do.

In jquery you need to give the id so this will help out