# Appending external PHP file in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-load

I'm referring a question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524228/how-to-load-php-file-into-div-by-jquery).

Trying to append an external PHP file in to jQuery and tried `load`.

```
$(".chatbox").load("./one.php");
```

This gives me the output;

> Your success message!

However the concern is this removes all HTML in the body and does not really **'append'** the success message.

I tried the following instead.

```
$(".chatbox").append("./one.php");
```

which merely prints this!

> ./one.php

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `load()` replaces the entire content of the selected element. It sounds like you simply need to change your `.chatbox` selector to a lower level element. If you want to append the content instead, then you would need to use `$.ajax()` to retrieve the value and `append()` it manually.

Comment: How would `append()` know that `./one.php` is a file?

Comment: you would need `$.get()` and use `$.append()` in the success callback. But read the documentation of jquery for all these functions (`load`, `get`, `append`) closely. They're quite clear and will most probably solve your question, or at least help you in asking a more specific question.

Comment: @giorgio make sense!

Comment: Read [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), [this](https://api.jquery.com/load/) and [this](https://api.jquery.com/append/), that will make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.load()` load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element. But you need to use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) that get data and return it into callback function.

```
$.get("./one.php", function(data) {
   $(".chatbox").append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in case if the page you're trying to load is failing due to some reason, you also need to handle the error block to inform you about the issue. Here is a more comprehensive way to do it. Here I have called a wiki page but you will know, all the php pages are in fact interpreted as valid html by PHP engine :)

```js
$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
  }
});


$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP",
  data: { },
  success: function(data){
    $('#demo').html(data);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('#demo').html("Status: " + textStatus + "<br/>Error: " + errorThrown);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```